# Слово "бардак"

Tags: этимология

Мне как-то в детстве сказали, что это слово чуть ли не матерное. Это правда? Какова его этимология?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее нет, чем да. Просто грубое, производное от фр. "бордель", то есть публичный дом.

Answer (score 4):

Если речь идёт о детстве,то слово в современном значении действительно не совсем приличное для ребёнка, ведь в словаре синонимов указаны такие:публичный( весёлый, розовый) дом, дом терпимости, бордель;  вертеп,  непотребный дом,  притон разврата, бедлам,  попойка, дом под красным фонарем,  шалман. Разве это приличные слова для ребёнка?
Это слово пришло в русский язык лет двести назад  из турецкого и означало (по Фасмеру) "глиняный горшок с широким отверстием". По-турецки bardak - "горшок, стакан". В России это слово прижилось на юге, у казаков.Они сравнивали бардак со словом кабак. Теперь это эвфемистическое преобразование слова бордель (из нем. Bordell или франц. bordel от ср.-лат. bordellum). 
Фасмер же упоминает и слово бордак - "публичный дом". По-видимому, позже бордак превратился в бардак. И стал означать неразбериху и беспорядок. Так же, как и бедлам или дурдом. Значение стало более нейтральным, бытовым.